# Howto bind Views to Viewmodel in a MVVM-Environment with XAML and WPF in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

if I want to bind a view to a viewmodel I add the following to the resources of my XAML-Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyViewModel}" >
        <views:MyView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Is there any possibility to add the (viewmodel,view)-resource-entry to my resources dictonary in C#-Code?

The following two lines create the key and add it to the dictonary:

```
DataTemplateKey key = new DataTemplateKey(typeof(MyViewModel));
View.WindowName.Resources.Add(key, value);
```

But how can I create the value from the `MyView` which must have the type `System.Windows.Baml2006.KeyRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code) is a sample on how you can create a datatepmlate with c# code.

ps: your question title should be something like how can a create a datatemplate with c# code. and this has btw nothing do to with mvvm. even more this code of course should not come into the viewmodel ;)

edit:

```
DataTemplate temp = new DataTemplate();
temp.DataType = typeof (MyViewModel);

FrameworkElementFactory fac = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MyView));

temp.VisualTree = fac;

View.WindowName.Resources.Add(new DataTemplateKey(typeof(MyViewModel)), temp );
```

its much more easy in xaml :)