# Creating DataTemplate from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for the not so very general question...

I have a ListView that I have to fill from code behind, and this ListView also need to get its GridViewColumn's from code behind.

For strings it wasn't hard to make the connection, but now I wan't to create a Ellipse that represents a Boolean value in the ListView.

The code in XAML is rather easy, but I fail at converting it to c# code.

Here is parts of the XMAL code:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateAdmin">
        <DockPanel>
            <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" Visibility="{Binding Path=isAdmin, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" Fill="Black"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name"/>
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource templateAdmin}"
                <GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <TextBlock Text="S"/>
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And by now I have gotten this far:
XAML:

```
<local:SortableListView >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="GroupListGridView" />
    </ListView.View>
</local:SortableListView>
```

And in code I have a `Collection<GridViewColumn> GridViewColumns` that I loop throug and add all items to the `GroupListGridView`. And I have a function to fill the `GridViewColumns` collection:

```
private void CreateGridViews()
{
    //Creating the Text was easy!
    GridViewColumns.add(new GridViewColumn(){ Header = "LastName", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("LastName") });

    //Creating the Ellipse was harder!
    GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
    DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

    gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("isAdmin");
    FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Ellipse));
    fef.SetValue(Ellipse.WidthProperty, 8.0D);
    fef.SetValue(Ellipse.HeightProperty, 8.0D);
    fef.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black));

    //I'm guessing that somewhere here there should be some binding to the visibility property and some sort of conversion done... But I can't figure out how!

    dt.VisualTree = fef;
    gvc.CellTemplate = dt;
    GridViewColumns.Add(gvc);
}
```

I don't think that I'm that far of... Just that I can't figure out those last steps!

Comment: Is there a really good reason for creating it in code behind?

Comment: clone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing lines are:

```
var ellipseVisBinding = new Binding("isAdmin");
ellipseVisBinding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();

fef.SetBinding(Ellipse.VisibilityProperty, ellipseVisBinding);
```

(I note that you've excluded the DockPanel in the template from your code version so I've removed that as well)