# WPF : Create CheckBox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I create this from code ?

```
<CheckBox Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=TimeTableInformationViewModel.MyCommand }"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding valueFromInput}" />
```

I am not sure how to set Command property from behind code :

```
    public static DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
    {
        var block = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        block.SetBinding(CheckBox.CommandProperty, new Binding(""));
        DataTemplate newDataTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = block };

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Is there a particular part you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TypeOfYourObject vmLocator = (TypeOfYourObject)Resources["VMLocator"];
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.Command = vmLocator.TimeTableInformationViewModel.MyCommand;
checkBox.CommandParameter = vmLocator.valueFromInput;
```

UPDATE >>>

There are a number of ways of doing this, but I have included a simple example that includes setting up a `Binding`... for more than this, please refer to the [How do I build a DataTemplate in c# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code) post to find out how to create a larger `DataTemplate` in code.

```
FrameworkElementFactory checkbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
checkBox.Name = "aCheckBox";
checkBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("YourBoolProperty"));
DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = checkbox };
```