# How to create DataTemplate dynamically and assign a StackPanel to it?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Lets say I want to make the following a DataTemplate:

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += button1_Click;
Button button2 = new Button();
button2.Click += button2_Click;

stackPanel.Children.Add(button1);
stackPanel.Children.Add(button2);
```

How can I turn this into DataTemplate? I tried creating an instance of DataTemplate class, but I see no method or property that would let me set the stackpanel above as the content of the DataTemplate object.

EDIT:
I am trying to do this in a Windows Store app.

Comment: I think you could try assigning the `StackPanel` to the `DataTemplate` object's `VisualTree` property, but that is just a guess.  Why don't you just build the template in XAML?

Comment: DataTemplate object doesn't have VisualTree property, unfortunately. And I can't do it in XAML for reasons that are too complex to explain right now :/
@TonyVitabile

Comment: Actually, according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx, it does.  It's inherited from `FrameworkTemplate`.

Comment: Yeah, but I am building a Windows Store app. The only availaible class named "DataTemplate" would be this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx
@TonyVitabile

Answer (score 4):

[The accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code) shows how you build a `DataTemplate` in the code behind.

```
//create the data template
DataTemplate objDataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
objDataTemplate.DataType = typeof(CreditCardPayment);

//set up the stack panel
FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
spFactory.Name = "myFactory";
spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal); // Use Oritentation.Vertical if appropriate.

//Your code for creating the buttons goes here.

//set the visual tree of the data template
objDataTemplate.VisualTree = spFactory;
```

That should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Store apps don't have access to the mentioned FrameworkElementFactory and DataTemplate classes :/
This is the only availaible class named DataTemplate:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx

Comment: Sorry, your question originally didn't say that.  Why don't you try building a test app with a simple `DataTemplate` in XAML in the window's resources, then get a reference to the resource & inspect it?  That will show you what you have to build, then you can back into what code to write to produce the similar template.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, will try that. Thank you!
@TonyVitabile

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `StackPanel`, add the `DataTemplate` object as a child of it.

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Children.Add(objDataTemplate);
```

Are you looking for this (although you will not able do it like this), or I misunderstood your question?

> UPDATE:
>   For the opposite

```
DataTemplate objDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StackPanel));
        FrameworkElementFactory stPanelElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        objDataTemplate.VisualTree = stPanelElement;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I am trying to do the opposite, assign StackPanel to DataTemplate.

Comment: If you have both, the `StackPanel` and the `DataTemplate`, then why are you trying to do the opposite?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Store apps don't have access to the mentioned FrameworkElementFactory and DataTemplate classes :/
@Debasis