# How to create DataTemplate in WinUI in C#?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, winui

How to create a `DataTemplate` in C# in a WinUI app, without having the template stored as a resource in XAML or loading from a XAML string (which is very slow)?

In WPF, it was possible using the `VisualTree` property, but this does not exist in WinUI.

Please note I'm already aware of this question: [How to programatically create a dataContext and assign a grid to it in c# (code behind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760752/how-to-programatically-create-a-datacontext-and-assign-a-grid-to-it-in-c-sharp) **which does not answer mine**

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do in WinUI (at this point) without XAML.  It is still way more limited than WPF.

Comment: @Nick Thanks. That's really really bad. I'm still trying to think of a way, there must be a way, even if it requires some little hacks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to create a `DataTemplate` programmatically in WinUI 3 is to use the [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.load?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) method.

It's unclear why you think this is "very slow" compared to using the `VisualTree` property and the `FrameworkElementFactory` in WPF. Less type safe and more error prone maybe but the performance shouldn't be an issue.

Besides, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) has long claimed that using the `FrameworkElementFactory` "*class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates*". The recommended approach is to use the `XamlReader` - even in WPF.

Comment: I really cannot use this approach, it's impossible in my case because the library I'm working on wants to give developers a way to use a delegate  without returns a FrameworkElement (`Func<FrameworkElement>`)

Comment: Well, you cannot turn a `FrameworkElement` into a `DataTemplate`. A template is a template and the only way to create one programmatically is to use `XamlReader.Parse`. Take it or leave it :)